# FileReader can't find File.json

Tags: java, json

I was trying to print what is inside this json document:

{
"Name" : "Daniel",
"Age" : 19
}

SO i wrote a code based on the next tutorial : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm

Here is my code:

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

try {
    String path = "File.json";
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(new FileReader(path));
    String name = (String)jsonObject.get("name");
    System.out.println(name);

}
catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();
}
catch (ParseException e3) {
    e3.printStackTrace();
}
```

when i run it, it throws no such file or directory. Please help. I established my resources route correctly i tested it with other files.

Comment: Presumably `File.json` doesn't exist in the working directory.

Comment: Is `File.json` in the same directory as with the `.java`/`.class` file?

Comment: @Rafael (Which isn't necessarily the same as the working directory, FWIW)

Comment: @Rafael Relative paths start from the current working directory, not simply where the class file is located.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for pointing that out.